# Repetition in Gnome calculator

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-calculator

I know that there are many *calculator* applications for GNOME. But, my question is for the specific `gnome-calculator` application that comes by default in Ubuntu. Currently, I am using its version 3.38.1 on Ubuntu 20.10.

Most conventional calculators allow to repeat the last operation by repetitively pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>=</kbd> key like this:

- 3+4<kbd>Enter</kbd> will display 7
- 3+4<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> will display 11
- 3+4<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> will display 15
- and so on.

Is there a method or workaround to do this in `gnome-calculator`? Currently, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>=</kbd> key the second time, the calculator displays the original expression and this is something I do not need. I also found nothing special in *Keyboard Shortcuts* on this.

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out? I am facing this issue, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, no solution so far... However, the KDE Calculator `kcalc` has a setting (under **General Settings**) called **Repeat operation for each result**. When this option is enabled, it works like the way I want. A similar option should be added to the GNOME Calculator.